# WebDriver synchronisation issue when waiting for an element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit4

Using WebDriver, Junit 4.11, Maven, IntelliJ v.13

Im trying to find the correct method in writing this test which is to verify that once I have clicked an element, it takes me to the next page.

After researching the WaitTool, Im attempting to nullify the `implicitlyWait()` then execute the `WebDriverWait()` and then reset `implicitlyWait()` although I'm receiving initialisation errors.

Ultimately, my main goal is to stop the synchronisation issues Im experiencing by using the new WaitTool.

The problem Im having is that when I click a button, I occasionally receive an error in waiting for an element `new WebDriverWait(chrome, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.listContainer")));`to appear on the next page.

This is what my code has been when executing the test:

```
@Test
public void selectBlankProject(){
    new WebDriverWait(chrome, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"templateGrid\"]/li[2]/img[1]")));

    WebElement item1 = chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"templateGrid\"]/li[2]/img[1]"));
    WebElement item2 = chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"templateGrid\"]/li[2]/img[2]"));
    WebElement item3 = chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"templateGrid\"]/li[2]/header/span"));
    WebElement item4 = chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"templateGrid\"]/li[2]"));

    Actions click = new Actions(chrome);
    click.moveToElement(item1).moveToElement(item2).moveToElement(item3).moveToElement(item4).click().build().perform();

    System.out.println("Blank Project has been selected");

}

@Test
public void dragVideoCompoenentOnToTheCanvas(){

    chrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    new WebDriverWait(chrome, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.listContainer")));

    Actions dragAndDrop = new Actions(chrome);
    //Dragging the video component onto the canvas
    WebElement listContainerVideo = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.listContainer"));
    WebElement componentListVideo = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.componentList.j-componentList"));
    WebElement videoComponent = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.componentItem.ui-draggable[data-id=\"c5\"]"));
    WebElement componentThumbVideo = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.componentThumb"));
    WebElement componentNameVideo = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.componentName.f-feature-A"));

    //finds the canvas to drop the video component onto
    WebElement canvas = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#page-c3"));

    dragAndDrop.clickAndHold(videoComponent)
            .moveToElement(listContainerVideo)
            .moveToElement(componentListVideo)
            .moveToElement(componentThumbVideo)
            .moveToElement(componentNameVideo)
            .release(canvas).perform();

    WebElement draggableVideoComponent = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.t-component-A.videoComponent.component.draggableComponent.ui-draggable.layerSelected"));

    Assert.assertEquals("video", draggableVideoComponent.getAttribute("data-type"));
}
```

I added `chrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` in the second test, then realised that this was also setting `WebDriverWait()`. So I came across `WaitTool` and I'm attempting to use this to see if it will solve my sync issue.

Reference here: [WaitTool](https://github.com/ChonC/wtbox/blob/master/src/wtbox/util/WaitTool.java)

However, this is causing me further problems. When I attempt to use the following code, I receive initialisation errors:

```
@Test
    public int dragClickAreaComponentToStage(int element){

    try{
        chrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        new WebDriverWait(chrome, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li.componentItem.ui-draggable[data-id=\"c3\"]")));

        chrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(DEFAULT_WAIT_FOR_PAGE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return element;
    }catch (StaleElementReferenceException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    WebElement clickArea = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.componentItem.ui-draggable[data-id=\"c3\"]"));
    WebElement arrowHead = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.componentThumb"));
    WebElement imageHolderClickArea = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.imageHolder"));
    WebElement componentNameClickArea = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.componentName.f-feature-A"));

    WebElement canvas = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.j-page.t-page-A[id=\"page-c3\"]"));

    Actions click = new Actions(chrome);

    click.clickAndHold(clickArea).moveToElement(arrowHead).moveToElement(imageHolderClickArea).moveToElement(componentNameClickArea).moveToElement(canvas).release();

    click.perform();

    //checking that the draggable click area component has a data-type value as clickArea
    WebElement clickAreaComp = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.t-componentImg-A.component.clickAreaComponent.draggableComponent.ui-draggable"));
    Assert.assertEquals("clickArea", clickAreaComp.getAttribute("data-type"));

        return element;

}
```

So in the stacktrace I'm getting

`java.lang.Exception: Method cDragClickAreaComponentToStage() should be void`

and

`java.lang.Exception: Method cDragClickAreaComponentToStage should have no parameters`

Okay, queue "So, what is your question?".

Firstly, I'd like to know where I'm going wring with setting my `@Test` public int. Usually I would have it declared as void, but in this case I want to `return` something which has to be an `int`, right?

Secondly, I'd like to know where am I going wrong with the synchronisation issue when it attempts to wait for an element.

Answer (score 0):

About your exceptions, if you are using JUnit @Test annotation, the test method must be `public void` with no parameters. [Reference](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html). If you want to use parameters, I find [this resource](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm) pretty helpful.

about setting the implicit wait

```
chrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I really see no value in doing this. At least I never set it and never see any of the exceptions you are getting.

About staleness of elements - this is happening occasionaly when something like data binding or whatever occurs. You can choose to ignore it. The wait method that i am using is:

```
/**
 * If no timeout is given, default to 60 sec.
 *
 * @param element - WebElement to wait for
 */
public void waitUntil(WebElement element) {
    waitUntil(element, 60);
}

/**
 * Waits for given WebElement to be present and visible (height and length > 1px) in DOM.
 *
 * @param element
 * @param timeOutInSeconds
 */
public void waitUntil(WebElement element, long timeOutInSeconds) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}
```

Comment: Sometimes I need to use an implicit wait and a `WebDriverWait` in the same method, hence trying to use the new `WaitTool`. So instead of using a `Thread.sleep()` I use a `implicityWait()` and as Im automating a GWT application I need to wait for the page to load, even if for a second as an element can be dropped in the 'old DOM' as it refreshes so quickly. So I'm trying out new (to me) techniques that will make my tests as robust as possible, so Im trying to experiment with try/catch and `public int` to `return` something. So this is this guidance Im looking for.